# display formated text in html from database (FLASK App)

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm currently building a recipe app where users can create their own recipies which are stored in a database. The user can enter the recipe ingredients and instructions in a textarea.

```html
<form action="/add_recipe" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipe_name" name="recipe_name" placeholder="Geef je recept een naam">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="ingredients" id="ingredients" cols="50" rows="10"
                  placeholder="Type hier al de ingredienten. Houd het leesbaar voor jezelf en anderen door de opmaak netjes te houden"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="instructions" id="instructions" cols="50" rows="15"
                  placeholder="Schrijf hier de instructies om het gerecht te maken"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group center-input">
        <label for="recipe_image">Wil je een foto toevoegen?</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="recipe_image" name="recipe_image">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Voeg het recept toe!</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This ends up in the following model

```
class Recipe(Base):
    __tablename__ = "recipes"
    recipe_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    recipe_name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    recipe_ingredients = Column(Text)
    recipe_instructions = Column(Text)
    recipe_image_url = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.user_id"))
    author = relationship("User", backref=backref('recipe', uselist=False))

    def __init__(self, recipe_name, recipe_ingredients, recipe_instructions, recipe_image_url, user_id):
        self.recipe_name = recipe_name
        self.recipe_ingredients = recipe_ingredients
        self.recipe_instructions = recipe_instructions
        self.recipe_image_url = recipe_image_url
        self.user_id = user_id
```

So far so good. The user fills in the form, puts all ingredients and instructions on a new line, and the recipe is saved in the database.
Only when i read the recipe from the database to display the recipe to a user the formatting is gone and the ingredients and instructions are displayed as a long string.

```
@routes.route("/recipe", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def recipe():

    if request.method == "POST":

        selected_recipe = DAO.fetch_recipe(request.form.get("selected_recipe"))
        author = DAO.fetch_author(selected_recipe.user_id)

        return render_template("recept.html", selected_recipe=selected_recipe, author=author)

    else:
        return redirect(url_for("/"))
```

```html
   {% block main %}
        <h2>Recept Pagina</h2>
    
            <img src="{{ selected_recipe.recipe_image_url }}"  class="mx-auto d-block" alt="">
    
            <h3>{{ selected_recipe.recipe_name }}</h3>
            <p>{{ selected_recipe.recipe_ingredients }}</p>
            <p>{{ selected_recipe.recipe_instructions }}</p>
    
    {% endblock %}
```

I have been crunching my brain over this way longer than i should, any help would be greatly  appriciated.

Comment: `recept.html` possible typo in template?  I would think this should throw an error, unless `recept.html` does actually exist and includes these vars without the formatting?

Comment: Very perceptive, some of the pages are named in dutch, so this is not a typo. The pages all render correctly. The only issue i have is the formatting of the paragraphs for the instructions and ingredients. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: What does the actual source (as seen by the browser) look like?  Has this rendered correctly or not.  `formatting is gone` is vague, so it would be good to know if these HTML tags even make it as far as the browser.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the text is displayed in the browser, it just does not look the way i wanted / expected it to. When i inspect the page and look at the rendered paragraphs the text actually is formatted the way it shoud be (in chrome devtools). So the text and even the formatting make it to the browser, only the paragraph tag ignores the whitespace. Looks like the fastest way is to use pre tags to retain the formatting and style those. Thanks for bearing with me, you hinted me in the right direction :)